# Seleccionar los registros que no estas en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta es la lógica en un proyecto participan muchos usuarios y un usuario participa en muchos proyectos, tengo estas tablas

```
projects
id |name       |
---|-----------|
8  |Proyecto 1 |
9  |Proyecto 2 |

projects_users
id |projects_id |users_id |role |
---|------------|---------|-----|
1  |8           |1        |1    |
2  |8           |3        |0    |
3  |8           |4        |0    |
4  |9           |8        |0    |

users
id |user_name |
---|----------|
1  |root      |
3  |Israel    |
4  |Hugo      |
8  |carmen    |
9  |alfredo   |
```

Lo que necesito es los usuarios que no participan en un proyecto por ejemplo los usuarios que no participan en Proyecto 1, lo que daría como resultado

```
id |user_name |
---|----------|
8  |carmen    |
9  |alfredo   |
```

lo que hacia en dos consultas

```
SELECT id FROM projects_users WHERE projects_id = 8;

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (1, 3, 4);
```

busco una manera de hacerlo con una consulta,

Gracias Gerry usando usa consulta anidada se obtiene el resultado

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM records_users
    WHERE records_id = 8
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la primera consulta dentro del  `WHERE` de la segunda:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT users_id
    FROM projects_users
    WHERE projects_id = 8;
  );
```